# Android JQuery mobile cookies not stored

Tags: jquery, android, cookies

I am using JQuery mobile library with jquery.cookie.js on Android. The header of index.html looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css-js/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" /> 
<script src="css-js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="css-js/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
<script src="css-js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="css-js/jquery.ba-dotimeout.js"></script>
```

Everything else works except storing and retrieving cookies.

The code to store them looks like

```
var tmp = 'abc'
$.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, tmp);
```

The code to retrieve looks like

```
var stored = $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME)
```

And i'm sure there are no empty or null values added. I have set

```
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

for the WebView.

What could be the problem, or what could be a good way to debug it?

Comment: What happens if you try to use document.cookies as described here: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html

Comment: What android version was affected?

Comment: 2.3, but that was 3 years ago :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue may be related to the fact that you are not setting a path:

```
$.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, tmp, { path: '/' });
```

Without the path, I believe the browser defaults to the current path (whatever page you are on), and as soon as you go to another page, the cookie is unaccessable.